# People's Republic of China's list of designated terrorist organizations?

Tags: policy, terrorism, china

The book *Routledge Handbook of International Criminology (edited by Cindy J. Smith, Sheldon X. Zhang, Rosemary Barberet)* says about [Tibetan Youth Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Youth_Congress):

> the organization is currently considered a terrorist organization by the Chinese government.

Where did they get this information?

Does People's Republic of China have an "official list of designated terrorist organizations", like [Canada](http://www.publicsafety.gc.ca/cnt/ntnl-scrt/cntr-trrrsm/lstd-ntts/crrnt-lstd-ntts-eng.aspx/Page/What_Governments_are_doingListing_of_Terrorism_Organisations) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations)?
If yes, where can it be seen? (preferably online)

The closest I could find is this [list of 4 organizations](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/xw/t56257.htm), hosted on `china-embassy.org`, but it does not list TYC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.pbc.gov.cn/publish/fanxiqianju/2838/2009/20091125142525553115271/20091125142525553115271_.html

This link gives 3 official sublinks of listed terrorist organizations and terrorists in China. The organizations are:

一、东突厥斯坦伊斯兰运动

二、东突厥斯坦解放组织

三、世界维吾尔青年代表大会

四、东突厥斯坦新闻信息中心

which I think is identical with the ones you found.

Comment: So I believe the most authoritative webpage is http://www.mps.gov.cn/n16/n983040/n1988498/1988553.html right? Could you please reflect that in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: This is only the first list of terrorist organization/terrorists. Note there are 3 pages. The second and third page contain various terrorists, but no new terrorist organization.

Comment: Yes, my question is only about organizations, not about people, so only http://www.mps.gov.cn/n16/n983040/n1988498/1988553.html is relevant.